# How to update or rename the attribute code of the attribute in magento 2

Tags: attributes, magento2.2.2, custom-attributes

How to update the attribute code of the attribute in magento 2.

I have refered below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198266/how-do-i-rename-an-attribute-code-in-magento

Answer (score 6):

You should use *Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup* in the Upgrade script or Data patch, as for Magento version > 2.3;

```
 $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->_moduleDataSetup]);
 $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
      'old_attribute_code',
      'attribute_code',
      'new_attribute_code'
 );
```

Comment: You'll also need to update the old_attribute_code to the new one wherever it is used in the source code (which may be nowhere or everywhere, depending on the codebase you're working with)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** As more recent answers show, there is now a method which can change the attribute code programmatically. I still wouldn't recommend doing it though.

Once the attribute code has been created, it cannot be edited through the admin. This is because Magento uses it as an internal identifier.
It does appear in some places in the admin (e.g. Manage Attributes section of the admin, or in places where it can be configured to appear, like grids or catalog/cart price rules).
The only place it can be seen on the frontend is as part of the URL for layered navigation filters, but that does mean it is intended to be used by your customers.

You could try editing it directly in the database, as noted in the linked answer, but this will break any extensions, custom development, etc which relies on that code. Magento will very likely be confused as well, which may lead to data corruption.

If the attribute is a custom one (not a system one) your best bet is to delete the attribute and create a new one with your new attribute code.

If the attribute is a system one (i.e. Created by Magento when you installed it) then I would strongly recommend not changing it - some attribute codes are hardcoded in the source code, e.g. In interfaces. You will break a lot of things.

Comment: Any ideas on what exactly can break in Magento? and where exactly the codes are used? We may need to do this and deleting and creating a new one is not an option because we already have products using the attribute.

Comment: @Jorjani Did you manage to find out what could break if code is changed directly to database?

Comment: Attribute codes can be referred to in the source code, so if you change it in the database but there are other modules/tests using it, they will now break, because the attribute in the source code no longer exists

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't comment yet (not enough reputation), I just want to note that the attribute code **does** actually appear to the user - specifically, when you filter a product list the attribute code is used in the URL. So it does help to have meaningful (and appropriate) code names.

For myself when solving the same problem with a custom attribute (why I found this topic), I solved the issue by manually editing the database. Editing the `attribute_code` field in the `eav_attribute` table and flushing the cache is enough to resolve this.

Comment: Editing my newly created attribute's code in the database seems to work fine. Much better than manually entering all the options again!!

Comment: @00-BBB Have you noticed any problems after changing the attribute code? I might need to do the same soon. Did you have configurable products with that attribute code in use?

Comment: @Webninja Not noticed any problems (*but* it was a completely new attribute, not even added to any products / attribute sets yet). So no configurable products were using it. But in theory, if it's not referenced in code anywhere it *should* be OK? But it is definitely possible that changing a variable that's in use could indeed break things  Sorry to not have the real answer!

Comment: I'd agree with the _should_ be ok. My own experience with this was also with a relatively new attribute - I'd definitely suggest caution on older attributes (backup database first, etc.) That said, when it comes to database itself, relations with other tables are generally based on the attribute id - the code generally sees more use in frontend templates or api calls.